# Singleton in Objective-C, compatible with ARC and thread safe

Tags: objective-c, singleton, automatic-ref-counting

I want to have a thread safe, ARC compatible singleton, but is seems to me that the most common example of singleton that I find, an example pasted here:

```
+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance
{
    static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

doesn't stops other developer from calling [[MyClass alloc] init] and overriding the desired flow.
What is the proper way to handle it (apart from throwing exception in init)?

Comment: I'm not sure you can stop developers doing that.  I guess you'll have to enforce your class's usage through documentation, or perhaps by refusing to work properly if your class is not the first and only instance created.

Comment: the best way is make everything as class method and make ivars become static global variable. you can pass Class object around and use it just like other object

Comment: sorry @xlc0212 but I don't follow:)

Comment: @trojanfoe, it is not quite true, he can stop them...

Comment: @holex Agreed - and that's an interesting solution - but is it worth the bother?  If people want to misuse your classes, then let them - there is enough to do solving the problem without worrying about things like that.

Comment: @trojanfoe, to be honest, it is just a solution for when you definitely don't want the developer to misuse your singleton class. you would throw an `NSException` if the developer tries to call the `+alloc` method twice, but it is optional only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you also have to override the `+alloc` method to avoid to allocate more than one instance of the singleton.

**EDIT#3:** *well, I **really** know what the official documentation says about overriding the* `+alloc` *method, but to achieve the asked benefit there is no way to avoid it. personally I don't agree to do it but it can provide the desired result.*

it would be like this:

```
static MyClass *_sharedInstance = nil;
static BOOL _bypassAllocMethod = TRUE;

+ (id)sharedInstance {
    @synchronized([MyClass class]) {
         if (_sharedInstance == nil) {
              _sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
         }
    }
    return _sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)alloc {
    @synchronized([MyClass class]) {
         _bypassAllocMethod = FALSE; // EDIT #2
         if (_sharedInstance == nil) {
              _sharedInstance = [super alloc];
              return _sharedInstance;
         } else {
              // EDIT #1 : you could throw an exception here to avoid the double allocation of the singleton class
              @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@: %p> Double allocation issue", [_sharedInstance class], _sharedInstance] reason:@"You cannot allocate the singeton class twice or more." userInfo:nil];
         }
    }
    return nil;
}

// EDIT #2 : the init method
- (id)init {
    if (_bypassAllocMethod)
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"invalid allocation" reason:@"invalid allocation" userInfo:nil];

    if (self = [super init]) {
    }

    return self
}
```

---

**EDIT #1**

you don't definitely need to throw an exception here but it is much more visual feedback for the developers of they use your class in wrong way, than sending back a simple `nil` pointer.

**EDIT #2**

I've added a simple trick to avoid the developers instantiate the class to bypass the modified `+alloc` method, in that case the allocation will work well but the `-init` will throw an exception.

Comment: I guess you'd need to override `-init` as well, adding *custom* functionality, else it would wipe out any current values?

Comment: the `-init` is currently the regular init method, if you want want to override to specify it, you could do it, but it is not necessary for avoiding of developers alloc two instances of the singleton class.

Comment: I disagree.  I think you need to at least use an *init flag* or something to stop re-initialising instance variables.

Comment: the `-init` method won't create another instance of the singleton class, if you want to avoid to init it twice, you could override the `-init` method as well, but it was not part of the original question. everyone should have imagination to extend it for their own wishes. it is an idea only.

Comment: Sorry to be awkward, but I think it's important.  If you don't have *special processing* in the overridden `-init` method then your solution will fall apart, plain and simple.

Comment: you are able to call the `-init` method many times as you want in your code, because it is an instance-method. I'm trying to tell you, it is not important part of the current question, because it depends on your personal wishes. if you want to avoid to run the `-init` method twice or more in your singleton class for any specific reason, you will find a way to add something to avoid it. that is a very basic thing, and it is not a _common_ problem currently.

Comment: **EDIT**; the code in my comment did not demonstrate the issue; this code should. Imagine if the class has instance variables (say an `NSMutableString *` called `string`), then this code would not produce the expected results, and it wouldn't be obvious why not: `MyClass *i1 = [MyClass sharedInstance]; [[i1 string] appendString:@"hello"]; MyClass *i2 = [[MyClass alloc] init]; NSLog(@"%@", [i1 string]);`

Comment: re-init may discards previous states and therefore cause problem.

Comment: yes in that case `i2` will be `nil`, it is the behaviour I expected, I could throw an exception to terminate the application of the irregular using of singleton class (`MyClass *i2 = [[MyClass alloc] init];`), I was just gentle, but I think I edit my answer.

Comment: Actually I don't think my code demonstrates the issue anyway as I missed the fact that `+alloc` will return `nil` if there is already an instance of this class in existence.  I therefore think this solution is correct.

Comment: @trojanfoe, yep, I've edited my answer, so when someone tries to allocate the singleton class again, I will throw an exception. I think it is a bit better feedback for preventing of the double allocation than a simple `nil` pointer, which was a bit "invisible" solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Borg pattern instead of the Singleton pattern: Allow multiple instantiation of your class and have the instances share the same static state.

```
// Shared data
static NSDictionary *sharedData = nil;

+ (void) initialize {
  // Initialize shared data
  sharedData = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
}

- (id) init {
  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
    self.data = sharedData;
  }
}
```

This way, clients may arbitrarily use static `getInstance` methods or `init` methods, and receive objects sharing the same state. They need not even be aware that it's a singleton.

Comment: After some thought, I decided this is a way to go and will reengineer a couple of my singleton classes this way. This makes your infrastructure really flexible -- you'll be able to "unsingle" the singleton if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the following: (with newer `instancetype` compiler syntax)

```
@implementation MyClass

+ (instancetype)myClass {
  static MyClass *singleton; // keep global variables in the most minimal scope

  if (singleton == nil) @synchronized (self) {
    singleton = [[MyClass alloc] initPrivate];
  }

  return singleton;
}

- (instancetype)initPrivate { // ARC requires the method start with "init…"
  self = [super init];

  return self;
}

- (instancetype)init {
  return nil;
}

@end
```

This also doesn't **prevent** others from calling `[[MyClass alloc] privateInit]` but it will warn them (unless they write their own hushing code).

This would also leak pre-ARC if someone calls `[[MyClass alloc] init]` - but you've got bigger problems if that happens.  Optionally, you could throw an exception when init is called. (as in holex's answer)

Also, subclasses could theoretically get in a race condition.  If you're worried about that change `@synchronized (self)` to `@synchronized ([McClass class])`. I prefer the `self` as cleaner code and I know there won't be subclasses.

Comment: I'm not sure why `alloc init` will leak. As you returned `nil` from `init` the allocated memory has a reference count of 0 and should be deallocated. Am I missing something?

Comment: with ARC it should be cleaned up, as you mentioned.  I'll edit that for clarification.  (I've been coding Objective-C for 2 decades without ARC, so that was my default mind set when I was writing this) Pre-ARC, the call to alloc would create the space, without a call to release/dealloc it would leak.

Answer (score 0):

convert instance to class method and use the Class object as the singleton.

for example you have a singleton class like this

```
@interface MySingleton {
    int count;
}

+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance;
- (int)getNext;

@end
```

I am suggesting you to convert it to

```
@interface MySingleton

+ (int)getNext;

@end
```

in MySingleton.m

```
static int count;
```

then you can use it like

```
[MySingleton getNext];
```

or

```
id obj = [MySingleton class]; // Class objects are singleton provided by runtime
[obj getNext];
```

---

**EDIT**

I just want to point out, there are already so many ObjC implementation for singleton pattern.

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html
https://github.com/fadingred/objc-singleton

simple google search will find them. everything are considered. (much more than what I was expected)

Comment: yes, it is nice, but how does it solve the original problem? you also can allocate many instances of the `MySingleton` class when you call the `[[MySingleton alloc] init]`...

Comment: but object returned by `[[MySingleton alloc] init]` will be useless because nothing is implemented. then people will know it is mistake to call it. and you can always override `alloc` to return `[self class]` and implement `+[init]` to return the same

Comment: yes, but in my case the singleton class allocated only once, no matter how many times you want to call the `[[MyClass alloc] init]`. from the second time the alloc provides a `nil` value, so you are not able to allocated twice or more. (you also could throw an exception in the second time to the developers to force them to use the `+sharedInstance` class method.)

Comment: The point is, why will people call `alloc init`? it is clear they are deal with class method and you don't crease instance to access class method.

Comment: because they **can** do it, and the original question is about how we can force the singleton class would be allocated only **once**...

Comment: sure, the class object can only be allocated once (by runtime). people always can do `[NSObject new]` and get a useless object, but what is the point of to stop it?

Comment: _only one_ instance of the singleton class should be in the memory, this is the point you lost.

Comment: No. the Class object (`[MyClass class]`) is guaranteed to be singleton by runtime.

Comment: ...and who guarantees it? if I call the `[[MySingleton alloc] init]` method e.g. five different place in the code, I will get back five different instances of the `MySingleton` class. it is definitely not desired behaviour of singleton class, isn't it? I think you don't understand the meaning of _singleton_.

Comment: come on.. I am talking about the Class object, not the instance object. Also, you can always use `class_createInstance` to bypass `alloc` and create multiple instance of any class. There is simply no way to stop it.

Comment: you cannot use `class_createInstance()` runtime function with the `ARC`, and using the `ARC` was a condition of the original question... I still don't agree with your opinion, which says _there is no way to stop it_ because there **is** way.

Comment: ok. but you can use `objc_msgSendSuper` and invoke `[NSObject alloc]` on any class. Or you can even swizzle the implementation of `alloc`. There are too many ways to bypass it. ObjC is a dynamic language.

Comment: you ignore a simple fact you should not do: you **cannot** invoke any class method via the `objc_msgSendSuper`, therefore you cannot invoke the `+alloc` method either, because it is _definitely_ a class method. it only works with the instance methods, but for this you first have to instantiate the class via the overridden `+alloc` method. so, at current stage we still **can** stop developers to create two or more instances of the singleton class.

Comment: wrong again. every method are instance method. class method are instance method of meta class. just try this code and see https://gist.github.com/4701043

Comment: hey, you have finally found an example which works. you would not say I'm wrong (and the _again_ is more than bad word here), because until now you ware not able to provide any working solution to prove your theory is right, and unfortunately I'm still right everything because this example does not change the facts what I've mentioned. furthermore it is definitely not the right way to use the singleton classes, it is open and direct misuse them.

Comment: you __cannot__ stop developers to create two or more instances of the singleton class. and i __can__ invoke any class method via the objc_msgSendSuper. anyway, these are hacks and should not be used. but my point is there is no way to stop developer been silly (by create multiple instance of singleton) so i personally don't bother to make any "true" singleton class.

Comment: actually, I **have found** a way to check how the class has been allocated, and if my modified `+alloc` method bypassed using any of your examples, the `-init` method will throw an exception for the developers. I still **can** stop them in much easier way than how they implement the tricky code to call the super's `+alloc` instead of mine. so, what is the point now? **EDITED:** personally I'm not bothered when someone uses thousands instances of the singleton class, it is just a good brain training.

Comment: ok, i agree no more point for the discussion. it is fun to hack and break code anyway.